# Bind a Path Stroke color to Foreground

Tags: silverlight-4.0, controltemplate

Using the `TabControl` element for Silverlight in Blend I created the following markup:

```
<controls:TabControl>
    <controls:TabItem Header="TabItem" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}" />
    <controls:TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}">
        <controls:TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Path Data="M0,14L0,6 5,0 10,6 10,14 0,6 10,6 0,14 10,14"
                    StrokeLineJoin="Round" Margin="0 0 6 0"
                    Stroke="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="TabItem"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:TabItem.Header>
    </controls:TabItem>
</controls:TabControl>
```

`TabItemStyle1` is a copy of the default style of a `TabItem`.
I altered `TabItemStyle1` by adding a color animation in the `MouseOver` storyboard so that unselected tab items become red when the mouse hovers them:

```
<ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
    Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderTopUnselected"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
    To="Red" />
```

Now when I hover the second tab, the text becomes red but the Path remains black:
[image: Hovered second tab header]

How should I define the Path Stroke color to make it follow the same rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by binding the header content brushes to `{TemplateBinding TextElement.Foreground}`.

In other cases I used standard property binding with converters, for example if I had to adapt element's brushes to item state.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
<controls:TabControl>
    <controls:TabItem Header="TabItem" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}" />
    <controls:TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}">
        <controls:TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Path Data="M0,14L0,6 5,0 10,6 10,14 0,6 10,6 0,14 10,14"
                    StrokeLineJoin="Round" Margin="0 0 6 0"
                    Stroke="{Binding ElementName=textBlock, Path=Foreground}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="TabItem"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:TabItem.Header>
    </controls:TabItem>
</controls:TabControl>
```

Comment: Well it works for the initial color, but doesn't react to color changed by the animation. Can anybody explain how the TextBlock works, as it behaves correctly in this scenario?

Comment: @Mart- Unfortunately with Silverlight, that code is all hidden. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010(v=vs.95).aspx) describes the inheritance behavior, which basically includes Controls and TextBlocks. I will try to look at your sample in more detail later.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a perfect solution but you could use this

```
<sdk:TabControl>
        <sdk:TabItem Header="item1"></sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem Foreground="Red" x:Name="someNameForTheTab">
            <sdk:TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--Just set stroke binding to the foreground of the tabItem-->
                    <Path Stroke="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=someNameForTheTab}" Data="M0,14L0,6 5,0 10,6 10,14 0,6 10,6 0,14 10,14"                    
                          StrokeLineJoin="Round" Margin="0 0 6 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="item2"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </sdk:TabItem.Header>
        </sdk:TabItem>
    </sdk:TabControl>
```

Comment: This only works with the Foreground you set explicitly on the TabItem. The color changed in the animation still only applies to the text, not the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to the TemplatedParent like this:

```
<Path 
Data="M0,14L0,6 5,0 10,6 10,14 0,6 10,6 0,14 10,14" 
StrokeLineJoin="Round" 
Margin="0 0 6 0" 
Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

I haven't tested this, but give it a whirl and let me know. If it doesn't work, try this:

```
<Path Data="M0,14L0,6 5,0 10,6 10,14 0,6 10,6 0,14 10,14" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Margin="0 0 6 0">
    <Path.Stroke>
       <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Foreground.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </Path.Stroke>
</Path>
```

I have a feeling that the Color property needs to be the source of binding, not the actual brush.

Comment: I tried both variants with no success. The path is not drawn at all being at first display or on MouseOver. But I believe there could be a mismatch between Brushes and Colors...

Comment: The storyboard you have is changing the SolidColorBrush.Color property. So I think you need figure out how to share a binding with that. Also, TextBlocks have some kind of a magic cascading Foreground color binding. I think you may have to create your own control that inherits from TabItem and add a new Icon content property.

Answer (score -1):

// animazione periferica

```
    public static void LineAnimation(Line _line,String _colore)
    {
        Storyboard result = new Storyboard();
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
        animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        animation.Duration = duration;
        switch (_colore.ToUpper())
        {
            case "RED": 
                animation.From = Colors.Red;
                break;
            case "ORANGE": 
                animation.From = Colors.Orange;
                break;
            case "YELLOW": 
                animation.From = Colors.Yellow;
                break;
            case "GRAY": 
                animation.From = Colors.DarkGray;
                break;
            default: 
                animation.From = Colors.Green;
                break;
        }

        animation.To = Colors.Gray;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, _line);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(Line.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));
        result.Children.Add(animation);
        result.Begin();

    }
}
```

//**********************************************

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public Line _line;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        Canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp += Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp;
    }

    void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).X;
        _line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).Y;
        _line.Loaded += _line_Loaded;
        Canvas.Children.Add(_line);
    }

    void _line_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cls_Barriere.LineAnimation(sender as Line, "RED");
    }

    void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _line = new Line();
        _line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        _line.StrokeThickness = 5;
        _line.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
        _line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
        _line.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;

        _line.X1 = e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).X;
        _line.Y1= e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).Y;

    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```